# should we use ing after to get

Tags: gerunds

I was reading a magazine, and I faced this sentence:

> From 2005, it became really difficult to get funding for work on
>   something

I was curious to know why the writer has used funding rather than the fund.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Funding** is the word we use for the process of raising money from investors or institutions.

So the writer is saying that it was difficult to persuade people/institutions to provide the money that was needed for one or other project.

**Funds**, plural, signifies the money that it raised, whether for a single purpose or for multiple purposes.

Thus, it would have meant much the same if **funds** had been used instead of **funding**.

However, it would not be idiomatic to speak of **the fund**, which would refer to a particular fund. The writer is speaking about the difficulty of raising money in general, not of any particular fund.